# how to get company name in this html using python web scraping?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I am scraping the company names on yellowpages.com.au and I am stocked on how to find the correct element (div class) to find all the names.
Below is my python code and the url where I want to scrape the company name information.
Everytime, I run this code, I'm getting nothing.

````
``` import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests

url='https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=plywood&locationClue=Northern+Territory&lat=&lon='

response=requests.get(url)
print('ok')

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
page=soup.find_all('div', class_="body left")
print(page) ```
````

I have attached the image of the inspected website/url.

Hope you can help me to find the right element or re-writing my code.[image]

Comment: Its probably dynamically loaded page, you might want to consider using `selenium`.

Comment: The XPATH is something like `//a[@class="listing-name"]/text()`. But I can't test it, I need to pass a CAPTCHA first.

Comment: Thank you, I'm starting to learn selenium now but if you can write me a code it is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps consider the following free APIs

```
http://developers.sensis.com.au/docs/endpoint_reference
```

from:

```
http://developers.sensis.com.au/
```

See ToS:

```
http://developers.sensis.com.au/Terms_of_Service
```

They maintain a huge set of yellow and white AU business listings. API endpoints include `search`.

```
http://developers.sensis.com.au/docs/endpoint_reference/Search
```

Specs summary:

```
https://www.programmableweb.com/api/sensis-business-search-rest-api
```

Seems fairly straightforward from documentation. You need to register for an API key.